# Adding a property to an object causes a TypeScript error

Tags: typescript

I have struck what appears to be an obscure error in my TypeScript code that has me completely stumped, and searching the docs and Internet hasn't uncovered the reason.  I have included some fictitious code below that demonstrates the problem that I have encountered in my real project.  In this example code, the issue is around the "animals" object at the end of the code and the "for" loop that follows it.

With reference to the full code that is included at the end, if the animals object is as follows then there are no TypeScript errors.:

```typescript
let current = "carnivores";

const animals = {
  carnivores: [wildCarnivores, domesticCarnivores,],
  herbivores: [wildHerbivores, domesticHerbivores]
}

for (let animal of animals[current as keyof typeof animals][0].table) {
  console.log(`name: ${animal.name}; weight: ${animal.weight}`)
```

However, if I add any other property to the "animals" object as follows:

```typescript
let current = "carnivores";

const animals = {
  something: "hi",
  carnivores: [wildCarnivores, domesticCarnivores,],
  herbivores: [wildHerbivores, domesticHerbivores]
}

for (let animal of animals[current as keyof typeof animals][0].table) {
  console.log(`name: ${animal.name}; weight: ${animal.weight}`)
}
```

then I get the following TypeScript error:

> Property 'table' does not exist on type 'string | AnimalCategoryInterface'.
>     Property 'table' does not exist on type 'string'.

As an additional bit of information that may give a clue to the cause, if I hardcode "carnivores" (instead of using the value of the "current" variable) in the "for" loop then there are no TypeScript errors:

```typescript
let current = "carnivores";

const animals = {
  something: "hi",
  carnivores: [wildCarnivores, domesticCarnivores,],
  herbivores: [wildHerbivores, domesticHerbivores]
}

for (let animal of animals["carnivores"][0].table) {
  console.log(`name: ${animal.name}; weight: ${animal.weight}`)
```

The full source code is:

```typescript
interface AnimalInterface {
  name: string,
  weight: number,
}

interface AnimalCategoryInterface {
  table: AnimalInterface[],
}

const wildCarnivores: AnimalCategoryInterface = {
  table: [
    {
      name: "Lion",
      weight: 150,
    },
    {
      name: "Polar Bear",
      weight: 400,
    }
  ]
};

const domesticCarnivores: AnimalCategoryInterface = {
  table: [
    {
      name: "Cat",
      weight: 4,
    },
    {
      name: "Dog",
      weight: 20,
    }
  ]
};

const wildHerbivores: AnimalCategoryInterface = {
  table: [
    {
      name: "Deer",
      weight: 80,
    },
    {
      name: "Panda",
      weight: 100,
    }
  ]
};

const domesticHerbivores: AnimalCategoryInterface = {
  table: [
    {
      name: "Guinea Pig",
      weight: 1,
    },
    {
      name: "Horse",
      weight: 300,
    }
  ]
};

let current = "carnivores";

const animals = {
  something: "hi",
  carnivores: [wildCarnivores, domesticCarnivores,],
  herbivores: [wildHerbivores, domesticHerbivores]
}

for (let animal of animals[current as keyof typeof animals][0].table) {
  console.log(`name: ${animal.name}; weight: ${animal.weight}`)
}

for (let animal of animals["carnivores"][0].table) {
  console.log(`name: ${animal.name}; weight: ${animal.weight}`)
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgGwJLjTxLIDeAUMsiHJhAFzIDOYUoA5gDSXIDuEwdgAswjEAFdMAI2jcAvuXKhIsRCnRZcAYTiR2AeygBPAiuIoKVMHCk4GaDNnyFVSANoBdeYoT6QLPmAcABMdKAwAN0MIJkYNJx09QxMXc2QAXjIea1t7Nx4qSypimjpGACIAGWA-cu5i4v5BEUYARgBWAAZ64rkewoKS2ntygAV9HDgoZAAhCCm6waom4VFkABZO7sGFKg9yOQBuHz8A4P06FmAEMMjo2IdNHESIA2NTIjUMrKsbO0Z8g0ig1SiNEosGssBKtGOt+sg+oNgUMyshygARfTsCGQlYtZAAJm2DV2yH2RxO-jAgRCAAloFJgFEoDE4o5tLpXskPq4UJkijl-shAcVkVRQRV0RBoDiGni1gAOYm9eFi6jDCqjOAgYJwWWNaH41pbeGk8nHci+KnIc6XMDXelQRnM1mPBKct4pMxffnZP55JFLdWo8oAcXEoHmyFGgn1UOaa1aptVQYlaNphiYEDjfENawAzCadjxzYo7NSEOIoCzwN9yggpncWUxyharQFtU8mN8ikwLhAwEIOBUhziG+EmfcAbwgqFG5Pm5wbf2rjd5y6mJwvDwhAyF663DO6XuN0vbTF7QhHc77uTFDBDMgABTl5CdpzIfQwN-snBMNyVtWEC1nA3YANYQEYX7IGARgAA4QNB764EwHhuJ0HgAHSChAACUPzIO2EwQJhOBYk+AAGaYACSkMhOCYaCRy5gmjC0fRmHynIFG4Qc96Pi+A4-k8n7fvR-71uu9zlGhGHYf6+FFERdikeRVEasg7G-oxwzMfKbF0dpXE8QcQA)

Comment: Consider using `forEach` instead of `for..of` loop for proper type inference, See [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5L12w)

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine - Although that will work when `current` is a compile-time constant, I suspect it won't be in the user's real code, so there's still the issue of not narrowing the union: https://tsplay.dev/NDRxzW

Comment: @​HarrySmith - Is `current` hardcoded? E.g., is its type `"carnivores"`, not `string`? Or does it vary?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - thank you very much.  You are spot on with identifying the problem and I have marked your answer as the accepted answer.  Additionally, to help others who may encounter a similar problem and happen to look at this question, I have provided an answer below that simply expands on what you correctly identified as the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `something: "hi",` in `animals`, then `animals[current as keyof typeof animals]` is no longer an array type, since you've added a property of type `string`. So now the type of `animals[current as keyof typeof animals]` is `string | AnimalCategoryInterface[]`, not just `AnimalCategoryInterface[]`. But you're not handling that possibility in your code. Although `animals[current as keyof typeof animals][0]` remains valid either way (its type is `string | AnimalCategoryInterface`, since you can index into strings using `[0]`), but the `.table` part is invalid because strings don't have a `table` property.

Instead, make sure you have an `AnimalCategoryInterface` instance before trying to use it as an array, by adding a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards):

```typescript
const element = animals[current as keyof typeof animals];
if (typeof element !== "string") { // <== type guard
    for (let animal of element[0].table) {
        console.log(`name: ${animal.name}; weight: ${animal.weight}`);
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=70&ssc=1&pln=76&pc=1#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-8IEA+4AEIshyapWHYEBSQASjIZAAHp2OQAAeWiUPQ5AOAkJYwhKGAjGQAi2ywoUcGQTDyMojx+i8AA6GNWOLKgxwWCBVJwEkCIAA0TAASUhsJwVSCSudpdi6czLNU7V5CM5ieCdJklHE5YpPnGSfnk5DLLAvtT0+aovGUtSNLBbTWV0-TDJMqomEc2TrKqWzc3Sn5nNrMBXPcrygA)

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by T.J. Crowder correctly identifies the problem that I raised in my question, and I have marked his answer as the accepted answer.  However, to help others who may encounter a similar problem, I am also posting this answer to expand upon what T.J. Crowder identified as the problem in my code, and I also provide an alternative implementation of a solution to the problem.

In my original code, the animals object has three properties: "something", "carnivores", and "herbivores" as follows:

```typescript
const animals = {
  something: "hi",
  carnivores: [wildCarnivores, domesticCarnivores,],
  herbivores: [wildHerbivores, domesticHerbivores]
}
```

I also have a variable called "current":

```typescript
const current = "carnivores";
```

In my "for" loop, I use the variable "current" to index into the keys of the animal object.  To do so, I tell TypeScript that "current" is one of the keys of the animal object:

```typescript
for (let animal of animals[current as keyof typeof animals][0].table) {
  console.log(`name: ${animal.name}; weight: ${animal.weight}`)
}
```

The problem, as T.J. Crowder identified, is that the "table" property exists only on objects that implement the "AnimalCategoryInterface" but not all of the keys of "animal" are an array of "AnimalCategoryInterface" objects; specifically, the "something" key of animal is a string ("hi"), which does not have a "table" property, as the TypeScript error states:

> Property 'table' does not exist on type 'string | AnimalCategoryInterface'.
>    Property 'table' does not exist on type 'string'.

So, in other words, TypeScript is telling me, "It's all fine and dandy you telling me that "current" is one of the keys of "animal" but you could be referring to a key of "animal" that doesn't have a "table" property so I'm going to flag that as an error".

My alternative solution (to the one suggested by T.J. Crowder) is to move the "carnivores" and "herbivores" keys of "animal" into a nested "categories" object within "animal" as follows:

```typescript
const current = "carnivores";

const animals = {
  something: "hi",
  categories: {
    carnivores: [wildCarnivores, domesticCarnivores,],
    herbivores: [wildHerbivores, domesticHerbivores]
  }
}

for (let animal of animals.categories[current as keyof typeof animals.categories][0].table) {
  console.log(`name: ${animal.name}; weight: ${animal.weight}`)
}
```

I now refer to the "categories" object in my "for" loop and now, because all keys of the "categories" object are arrays of "AnimalCategoryInterface" objects (that all contain the "table" property), TypeScript is happy because now it can be sure that I am referring to a key that has the "table" property.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need split it into two functions. First one will check whether `current` is allowed, second one will iterate it.

```js
interface AnimalInterface {
    name: string;
    weight: number;
}

interface AnimalCategoryInterface {
    table: AnimalInterface[];
}

const wildCarnivores: AnimalCategoryInterface = {
    table: [
        {
            name: "Lion",
            weight: 150,
        },
        {
            name: "Polar Bear",
            weight: 400,
        },
    ],
};

const domesticCarnivores: AnimalCategoryInterface = {
    table: [
        {
            name: "Cat",
            weight: 4,
        },
        {
            name: "Dog",
            weight: 20,
        },
    ],
};

const wildHerbivores: AnimalCategoryInterface = {
    table: [
        {
            name: "Deer",
            weight: 80,
        },
        {
            name: "Panda",
            weight: 100,
        },
    ],
};

const domesticHerbivores: AnimalCategoryInterface = {
    table: [
        {
            name: "Guinea Pig",
            weight: 1,
        },
        {
            name: "Horse",
            weight: 300,
        },
    ],
};

let current = "carnivores";

const animals = {
    something: "hi",
    carnivores: [wildCarnivores, domesticCarnivores],
    herbivores: [wildHerbivores, domesticHerbivores],
};

type Animals = typeof animals

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type TupleProperty<T> = Values<{
    [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] extends any[] ? Prop : never
}>

const isTupleProperty = <
    Data extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>
>(data: Data, key: PropertyKey): key is TupleProperty<Data> =>
    key in data && Array.isArray(data[key])

const iterate = (data: Animals, current: TupleProperty<Animals>) => {
    for (let animal of data[current][0].table) {
        console.log(`name: ${animal.name}; weight: ${animal.weight}`);
    }
}

iterate(animals, 'herbivores') // ok
iterate(animals, 'something') // expected error

let key = 'any string'

if(isTupleProperty(animals,key)){
    iterate(animals, key) // ok
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m0ApoW)

`TupleProperty` - returns keys which are corresponds to array values

`isTupleProperty` - is custom typeguard which checks whether variable is allowed to use (whether key coresponds to array)

As you might have noticed, `something` is not allowed value for `iterate` function

---

**Pros:** You don't use type assertions at all

**Cons:** you have extra function instead of condition statement

P.S. Rule of thumb: if you have condition statement, think whether it can be transformed to custom typeguard. IT does not mean that each condition statement should be transformed, it should be at least considered